# Can I get warnings about overly-restrictive type signatures?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Can GHC or some lint tool tell me when I've provided a type signature for a function that could be more polymorphic?

Comment: Be aware that the most general type signature isn't always the best one. `asTypeOf` would be pretty meaningless if it had a more general type :) and less trivially, some type system techniques like regions rely on "unused" class constraints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GHC doesn't do this, and a quick search of Hackage turns up nothing.

A simple, but possibly quite effective way to implement such a thing would be to load the module in GHCi, use `:browse` to get all the type signatures, then load a copy without any type signatures, use `:browse` again, and compare the two outputs; then just print all the lines that differ beyond parentheses, whitespace and alpha-renaming. However, this wouldn't work perfectly, especially if you have definitions whose types can't be inferred.

I have a feeling such a tool would turn up a lot of false positives in practice.